# Keyword Query to get value from ContentType Column

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom, kql

I have problem how to get value of column inside contentype of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Przn.png) via keyword Query in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide

i want to get value of any containt SRSItemType = record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `SRSItemType` column is mapped in Managed Property. If it isn't mapped in Managed Property you can't use it in KQL.

Look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzyLCZPd3d8

Comment: excuse me how to check column mapped in managed property?

Comment: Here you go https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2232112&seqNum=4